# Strange border in Youtube thumbnail

Tags: html, css, youtube-javascript-api

I want to embed a Youtube video in my page, and I want to use the same background color for both, my video and my web page.

I use this code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="ytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/u-fvcm2mx7A?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;theme=light&amp;color=white" style="width: 400px; height: 225px;">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine, when I play the video I can see it fully integrated. But the the thumbnail loaded before playing the video, sometimes has strange top and right borders.

If I use bigger sizes, maintaining the aspect ratio (16:9), the borders do not show.
I have tested in Linux and Windows, and IE, Firefox and Chrome, and with other videos but the problem persists in all of them.

Thanks